# iOS shapes animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, shapes

I'm actually starting my first app development and before laying out the structure of the app itself i need to understand how i can accomplish complex shapes animations with `UIKit` (possibly).

I came across to an animated picture on [Dribbble](https://dribbble.com) and i would like to replicate that effect in a test app, just to understand how this kind of animations are accomplished.

[This](https://dribbble.com/shots/1623679-Open-Close?list=searches&tag=ios&offset=2) is the animation I'm talking about...

Firstly I thought that I could create a keyframe animation (multiple images) and then animate it, but sounds pretty inefficient. So probably I would need to use `UIBeizerPath` or some other core graphics stuff.

What would you suggest me to do to re-create that effect? 
Thanks in advance.

P.s: Possibly if you will include code snippets, Obj-C would be the best choice instead of swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This site has a good break down](http://robb.is/working-on/a-hamburger-button-transition/) of how you'd accomplish this.

Basically, you use a shape layer with the path as the entire curve taken by the middle line during the animation. You then use the stroke start and stroke end properties of shape layer to transition from the horizontal line to the circle. You also have two other shape layers that are two horizontal lines that rotate into a cross.